# How does one create custom filter conditions for array items upon ever newly computed query-data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filtering, multiple-conditions

I have a filter object that is returned by query params

`url = /all?channels=calls,text&calls=voicemail,missed`

```
const query = {
  channels: 'calls,texts',
  calls: 'voicemail,missed',
};
```

I then have an array of objects that come in from a socket.

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    channel: 'SMS',
    sent: '2021-08-22T03:21:18.41650+0000',
    sender: {
      contactType: 'business',
    },
    recipients: [
      {
        contactType: 'corporate',
      },
    ],
    direction: 'INBOUND',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    channel: 'VOICE',
    sent: '2021-08-20T23:15:56.00000+0000',
    sender: {
      contactType: 'business',
    },
    recipients: [
      {
        contactType: 'corporate',
      },
    ],
    callDetails: {
      answered: false,
      voicemail: true,
    },
    direction: 'INBOUND',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    channel: 'VOICE',
    sent: '2021-08-20T23:15:56.00000+0000',
    sender: {
      contactType: 'business',
    },
    recipients: [
      {
        contactType: 'corporate',
      },
    ],
    callDetails: {
      answered: true,
      voicemail: false,
    },
    direction: 'INBOUND',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    channel: 'VOICE',
    sent: '2021-08-20T23:15:56.00000+0000',
    sender: {
      contactType: 'business',
    },
    recipients: [
      {
        contactType: 'corporate',
      },
    ],
    callDetails: {
      answered: false,
      voicemail: false,
    },
    direction: 'INBOUND',
  },
];
```

I want to filter out the objects that match the filters but the `query` obj isn't friendly enough to just map the `arr` through.

With the query obj shared above, i should return the objects `id:1` and `id:2` and `id:4` from `arr`, since those object meet the criteria of `sms, voicemail, & missed`

I assume i need a modified query obj that has to have various conditions available for each property, i.e `calls: voicemail === callDetails.voicemail === true` or `calls: received === callDetails.answered === true`

I've seen lots of examples on how to filter an array of objects with multiple match-criteria, but with the req of the property having multiple conditions, i've hit a wall.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to provide kind of a ***rosetta stone*** which does bridge/map the `query` specific syntax with any list item's specific data structure. Thus one will end up writing a map which takes a `query`'s structure into account but ensures for each necessary query endpoint an item specific filter condition/function.

The query function should simply [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the item list by applying a list of logical OR conditions, thus using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for returning the boolean filter value.

Which leaves one of implementing a helper method which collects ... *via [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) as well as via [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)* ... the function endpoints from the above introduced `requirements` configuration/map, based on the `query` object, provided by the system. Thus this helper might be named `resolveQuery`.

```js
const sampleList = [{
  id: 1,
  channel: 'SMS',

  direction: 'INBOUND',
}, {
  id: 2,
  channel: 'VOICE',

  callDetails: {
    answered: false,
    voicemail: true,
  },
  direction: 'INBOUND',
}, {
  id: 3,
  channel: 'VOICE',

  callDetails: {
    answered: true,
    voicemail: false,
  },
  direction: 'INBOUND',
}, {
  id: 4,
  channel: 'VOICE',

  callDetails: {
    answered: false,
    voicemail: false,
  },
  direction: 'INBOUND',
}];

// prepare a `requirements` map which ...
// - on one hand maps `query`-syntax to a list items's structure
// - and on the other hand does so by providing an item specific
//   filter condition/function for each necessary query endpoint.
const requirements = {
  channels: {
    texts: item => item.channel === 'SMS',
  },
  calls: {
    voicemail: item => item.channel === 'VOICE' && !!item.callDetails.voicemail,
    missed: item => item.channel === 'VOICE' && !item.callDetails.answered,
  },
}
// const query = {
//   channels: 'calls,texts',
//   calls: 'voicemail,missed',
// };

function resolveQuery(requirements, query) {
  const reject = item => false;

  // create/collect a list of filter condition/functions
  // which later will be applied as logical OR via `some`.
  return Object

    .entries(query)
    .flatMap(([ groupKey, groupValue ]) =>
      // e.g groupKey => 'channels',
      // groupValue => 'calls,texts'
      groupValue
        .split(',')
        .map(requirementKey =>
          // e.g requirementKey => 'calls'
          // or requirementKey => 'texts'
          requirements?.[groupKey]?.[requirementKey?.trim()] ?? reject
        )
    );
}

function queryFromItemList(itemList, requirements, query) {
  const conditionList = resolveQuery(requirements, query);

  console.log(
    'conditionList ... [\n ',
    conditionList.join(',\n  '),
    '\n]'
  );

  return itemList.filter(item =>
    conditionList.some(condition => condition(item))
  );
}

console.log(
  queryFromItemList(sampleList, requirements, {
    channels: 'calls,texts',
    calls: 'voicemail,missed',
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @victorjaquez ... Thanks, but do you also gain something from the approach?

Comment: only issue i see is, if i have for example 'channels: text, direction: inbound'

i would still get voice/calls inbound.. when the expected output is all text thats inbound. Any idea how to approach? essentially the query is currently returning all objs that match each groupValue.

Comment: @victorjaquez ... 1/2 ... Of cause I implemented your requested use case with all/just the information that were available then. I neither know of other possible keys and values within a `query` objects nor do I immediately know what they would target within the data structure. But the approach is generic. One of cause has to maintain the *"Rosetta Stone"* `requirements`. There one is in full control of the `query`, its keys/values and the conditions which are responsible for filtering an item.

Comment: @victorjaquez ... 2/2 ... If it comes to mixed or nested AND / OR conditions, then one has to come up with yet another much more complex approach. And in such a case one needs to know the requirements in their entirety.

Comment: @victorjaquez ... At this point one already can say that the `query` object's structure has to be entirely rebuilt in order to enable a still generic but more complex / more capable function based filter approach.